# Sound setup has with different volume on different systems

Tags: usb, audio, speakers

I have a small audio setup for my speakers. First, there is a USB audio interface and connected to this are my speakers. The audio interface is connected to my pc and also sometimes to my laptop but then I was wondering about something:

When the audio interface is connected to my laptop, the sound from my speakers is nearly double the volume if I would connect it to my pc.

How can this be? Both run the same windows version, all sound windows controllers are at maximum. Shouldn't the volume be the same because it is a USB device?

Comment: Does the USB audio interface have a volume control on it?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes

Comment: So is that turned down too much?

Comment: Its like half up, but I don't change it when using it on the laptop or pc

Comment: Can you show us what audio interface it is please?

Comment: It is the Behringer U-Phoria UMC22